# Map to any struct

Tags: c++

I'm using c++.
I want to create a `map` to store any struct in my project.
I.e I have the structers:

```
struct My_Struct1{ int x;}
struct My_Struct2{float y;}
...
```

And i want to declare a map:

```
MyMap[MessageID1] = My_Struct1_obj;
MyMap[MessageID2] = My_Struct2_obj;
....
```

Which type the `MyMap` should be?

```
map<unsigned int, ? > MyMap;
```

If i do `map<unsigned int, void* >` how i can know if i want to  access to `int x` or to `float y` ? I need to do switch case on MessageID?

After i have got the message i want to copy some data from the match block..

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? How do you, later on, know if map contains `My_Struct1` or `My_Struct2`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easier way would be to create a base class for all your structures and store pointers to that in the map.

```
struct BaseStruct
{
    virtual ~BaseStruct()
    {}
};
struct My_Struct1 : BaseStruct { int x; }
struct My_Struct2 : BaseStruct { float y; }

std::map<unsigned int, BaseStruct *> MyMap;
```

Or you may prefer using a smart pointer to handle the lifetime of the objects.

```
std::map<unsigned int, std::shared_ptr<BaseStruct> > MyMap2;
std::map<unsigned int, std::unique_ptr<BaseStruct> > MyMap3;
```

Note the virtual destructor. That is important so that when you delete the objects from the map the memory of the subclasses is properly freed.

PS: Take a look at [`boost::any`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/doc/html/any.html). It may be useful if you don't want or can't use the base struct.

Comment: if i.e i cant touch on My_Struct1, My_Sturct2 what i can to do?

Comment: @Evyatar: You can wrap them in another struct: `struct WrapStruct1 : BaseStruct { My_Struct1 data; };`. Or if you feel brave: `struct WrapStruct1 : BaseStruct, My_Struct1 {};`. And don't forget `boost::any`!

Comment: You don't need a virtual destructor when using `shared_ptr`

Comment: @MikeMB: While you are technically right, I would not advice using a non virtual destructor. They are cheap and it is easy to write wrong code without it.

Comment: @rodrigo: Especially, if they are the only virtual function, I wouldn't call them cheap. But then again, `shared_ptr` and `map` are pretty heavy weight themselves, so it probably doesn't make a real difference.

Comment: @MikeMB: And besides, they will probably want to do `dynamic_cast` or something similar, so the virtual stuff would be needed anyway.

Comment: @rodrigo: Of course, it always depends on the exact requirements of the OP, but when he says *"store **any struct** in my project"*, making any struct e.g. non-trivially-copyable, non-constexpr-able or making it harder for the compiler to inline any calls to the destructor throughout the program is a step that should not be taken lightly just for the sake of one data structure. Hence I think it is important to point out that a virtual destructor it is not necessary in that particular case although it might be advisable.

Comment: Actually I'm not happy with the whole concept of creating a common base class just to store otherwise completely independent objects in a common container, but unfortunately, we don't have a standard version of `boost::any` yet.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve that via inheritance, create a base struct and inherit both of your structs from that base struct (place some constructor to initialize the data member if you want).

```
//Your base struct
struct My_Base
{
    virtual void foo() {};
};

struct My_Struct1: virtual My_Base
{
public:
    int x;
    My_Struct1(int _x) { x = _x; }
};

struct My_Struct2 : virtual My_Base
{
public:
    float y;
    My_Struct2(float _y) { y = _y; }
};

map<unsigned int, My_Base*> _map;
```

To make it easily understandable, providing the driver or invocation code below.

```
My_Base* obj1 = new My_Struct1(2);
My_Base* obj2 = new My_Struct2(3.2f);

//Adding some random test data to map
_map[1] = obj1;
_map[2] = obj2;

My_Base* mapObjBase = _map.find(2)->second;
//Downcast the object you retrieved from the map, this downcasting could fail so please note the if here.
if (My_Struct2* mapObj2 = dynamic_cast<My_Struct2*>(mapObjBase))
{
    cout << "My_Struct2.y = " << mapObj2->y << endl;
}
else
{
    cout << "Error..." << endl;
}
//Some memory cleaning before leaving the code block.
delete obj1;
delete obj2;
```

Something about [dynamic_cast](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast) (if you are interested in further reading...)

Answer (score 2):

You should declare struct type in following way:

```
struct My_Struct
{
    union
    {
        int x;
        float y;
    };
};
```

Then you can use it in following way:

```
map<unsigned int, My_Struct> MyMap;
```

Comment: You should probably also keep some sort of type information.

Comment: @CodeFuller, i have something like 15 structers with up to 1000 variables, i cannot to create union for each struct.. i want something generic

Comment: @Evyatar in c++ a struct is like a class, just make them inherit from a base one, and keep track of what type is.

Comment: The OP uses C++. Unions should never be the first option, because they mess with the constructor/destructor semantics of the inner types. Use a proper class hierarchy instead.